# How to tangle/scramble/rearrange a string in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab

For an example exam question, I've been asked to "tangle" a string as shown:

```
tangledWord('today')='otady'
tangledWord('12345678')='21436587'
```

I understand this is an extremely simple problem but it's got me stumped.

I can make it produce a tangled word when the length is even, but I'm having trouble when it's odd, here's my function:

```
function tangledWord(s)    
n=length(s);    
a=s(1:2:n);    
b=s(2:2:n);    
s(1:2:n)=b;    
s(2:2:n)=a;    
disp(s);    
end
```

Comment: Just an aside, you can use the `end` keyword instead of `n` so `s(1:2:n)` where `n=length(s)` is the same as just `s(1:2:end)`

Answer (score 4):

For odd word length, you need to reduce `n` by `1` to leave the last char untouched. Use `mod` to detect odd word length.

Comment: in fact you can just use `n-mod(n,2)` for both odd and even cases

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scramble every char randomly, you can try:

```
string = '1234567';
shuffled = string(randperm(numel(string)))
```

> shuffled = 5741326

---

If you want to change the first two chars:

```
tangled = [string(2) string(1) string(3:end)]
```

> tangled = 2134567

---

If you want to change every two chars:

```
n = ( numel(string)-mod(numel(string),2));
tangled2 = [flipud(reshape(string(1:n),[],n/2))(:); string(n+1:end)]'
```

> tangled2 = 2143657

Answer (score 0):

```
function tangledWord(s)
n=length(s);
if mod(n,2) == 0
    a=s(1:2:n);
    b=s(2:2:n);
    s(1:2:n)=b;
    s(2:2:n)=a;
    disp(s)
elseif mod(n,2) ~= 0
    a=s(1:2:end-1);
    b=s(2:2:end-1);
    s(1:2:end-1)=b;    
    s(2:2:end-1)=a; 
    disp(s)
end
end
```

Comment: *"While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value."*

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.